# How to properly manage ansible variables and group_vars?

Tags: ansible

The scenario:

- A docker swarm with 1 manager and 3 workers
- Each host needs a firewall
- Manager firewall has specific ports
- Worker firewall has specific ports
- All nodes also have shared ports

all.yml

```
ports
  - 22
  - 2376
  - 2377
```

manager.yml

```
ports
  - 443
```

worker.yml

```
ports
  - 80
```

wanted output for manager node

```
ports
  - 22
  - 2376
  - 2377
  - 443
```

wanted output for worker node

```
ports
  - 22
  - 2376
  - 2377
  - 80
```

The question:

Being that ansible allows group_vars, and that the model is to **replace** vars instead of **merge**, how is it possible to manage the above scenario without having to repeat ports in each group_vars file?

I suspect the answer is to repeat vars. I have read about allowing ansible to use merge instead, but this only works for dictionaries not lists as above, and is frowned upon.

The reason I ask is that when using stock roles from galaxy, like a firewall role, it is damn near impossible (as far as I understand) to utilise group_vars properly and list based roles; it's one or the other.

The above example is over simplified, and in the real world a port definition is about 6 lines of config, and is obviously a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have not assigned `localhost` to another group besides `all`, you can reference that in `group_vars` files:

all.yml:

```
ports:
  - 22
  - 2376
  - 2377
```

manager.yml:

```
ports:
  - "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ports }}"
  - 443
```

worker.yml:

```
ports:
  - "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ports }}"
  - 80
```

Comment: That is a really snazzy answer! I'll try it out when I'm back at work. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the dot style: `hostvars.localhost.ports` instead of `hostvars['localhost'].ports`.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct

> the model is to replace vars instead of merge

Given the files are in the directory group_vars, an option would be to declare specific variables in manager.yml

```
manager_ports:
  - 443
```

and in worker.yml

```
worker_ports:
  - 80
```

Then, for example, let's merge the lists in the playbooks (not tested)

```
- hosts: manager
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ports: "{{ ports + manager_ports }}"

- hosts: worker
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ports: "{{ ports + worker_ports }}"
```

Details can be found in the section [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although coming from a programming background into devops, this seems a little odd to me and defeats the point of group_vars imo. That's a comment on ansible, not your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let

all.yml

```
ports_all
  - 22
  - 2376
  - 2377
```

manager.yml

```
ports_manager
  - 443
```

worker.yml

```
ports_worker
  - 80
```

Then you can define a task that merges all lists matching "ports_*" into a single list / fact:

```
- name: Combine ports
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    fact_ports: "{{ fact_ports | default([]) + item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup(ansible.builtin.dict', vars) | selectattr('key', 'match', '^ports_.*$') | map(attribute='value') }}"
```

Note that the availability of lookups and filters is version dependant in Ansible.